# Apache Module blocking access to FTP

Tags: centos, permissions, web-server, ftp

EDIT: previous server admin changed all sites to use Apache Module. Now the sites only run on apache:apache

Problem is, now the client can't access their files in Filezilla, since originally the user permissions were ~domainuser~:psaserv.

This, of course, doesn't allow the CMS to run. Is there a clean way to fix this?

Comment: Again, you should seek assistance from Parallels support for this Plesk-related issue.

Comment: I don't think this is specifically a Plesk related issue. This is a different question than the one I posted last week, and doesn't mention anything specific to Plesk.

Comment: With a little digging I was able to resolve the problem. The domain was running PHP as Apache module. When I switched it to FastCGI, I was able to restore the user permissions to ~username~:psaserv. After that FTP and web services work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cheap and dirty hack, but does work. Check out the man page for "chattr". Setup extended permissions on the directories and files which will allow a user to modify/delete it.

Being a cheap and dirty hack, it does imply there is probably a cleaner way to make this work "properly", however in the world where people need their stuff to work, this will save you time until you can do things properly.